# Show notification icon on status bar with React Native when app is not running on Android

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I have a situation on my React Native app, where user can start a timer and `isRunning` and `startTime` states are stored in the app so that it can display current running time when the app is in foreground even though the user quits the application at some point and opens it again.

Is there a way to show notification icon on status bar when the timer is running, but user has quit the application to indicate that the timer is currently "running" (actually it is not doing any operations on background) on background?

I have encountered some apps that display a silent notification that is not directly closable after I have quit the app, but I haven't seen a situation where status bar notification is present (together with notification) until some condition is met after the app is quit by the user.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and Firebase to push notifications in my app overall.

Answer (score 0):

React-Native manages only Active and Background/Inactive/Foreground state. When user kill the app. JS engine shuts down.

All you can use is Local Notification and Scheduled Notification. I also have one app in which user set a reminder time. And notification invoke at that specified time.

Using Firebase I guess you need to call api after some specific interval for push notification from server side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in background services or android development but here is my thought... I believe you could dig in and write some java android code for a background unstoppable service (persistent on app close or background states). You can do this by creating a bridge and using native modules to manage your background services. I came across a great [resource on medium](https://medium.com/reactbrasil/how-to-create-an-unstoppable-service-in-react-native-using-headless-js-93656b6fd5d1) that details the process of creating a background service, a broadcast receiver and maintaining Headless instance even when the app is closed or the device restarts.Hope that helps you achieve your goal.

### Edit

[This](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) ready made package will help you with better. Check it out. You actually don't have to write native android java code at all.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it!

Comment: Check https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job out